# Drupal 7.41 images not being displayed

Tags: media, .htaccess

I Have Drupal 7.41 site installed on a vps with centOS 6 PHP 5.5 using webmin as my control panel.
I have 2 htaccess files one in the root and 1 in the sites/default/files I have tried the following in the htaccess file in the sites folder
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch or
with # before each line but same result

but I still cant get images to be displayed. If I delete the htaccess file in the sites folder, I can then display the images until I run the cron and the new htaccess file is back in the sites folder and I can no longer display images.

Comment: do your folders have permission to read and write?